# MergAndroid Livecode - How to save on Android's Camera Roll?

Tags: android, livecode

I'm using this code to save an image in the Android's Camera roll, unfortunately to date without any luck.

```
  put mergStoragePath("pictures") into a
  put a & "/myphoto.jpg" into pathFile
  put the long id of image "myPhoto" into longIDofImage
  export longIDofImage to file pathFile as JPEG
```

All suggestions will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the media scanner isn't scanning the file. I have a command coming to do that `mergStorageScanFile`. However, to do what you want to do there's actually a built in LiveCode command `mobileExportImageToAlbum`.

Comment: Unfortunately, currently the command mobileExportImageToAlbum of LiveCode does not work on Android due to a bug, so the arrival of mergStorageScanFile is good news. Thanks!

Comment: PS It will also be useful to store other types of files such as video.

Comment: Yes, it should be able to scan any file.